# Talend Open Studio : creating table in MySQL dynamically

Tags: talend

I am trying to find out how to do dynamic creation of tables in MySQL using Talend.
In other ETL tools such as Pentaho they have a specific component called "metadata" to do this.
So my use case is the following:
1) Create database manually in MySQL
2) Use Talend to read CSV Header info, and use this as the fields of a table to be created in MySQL using Talend.

I have searched and could not find anything for this specific feature online.
[Note : using Talend Open Studio for Big Data Version: 6.4.1]

### UPDATE:

I have made progress on this, but running into issues trying to generate a primary key on the MySQL output using the NumericSequence function.
My data does not have natively a primary key, but wish to include one:
I have a screenshot of the tMap attached here:

[image]

Also I am getting a compile/build error. It seems it does not like the primary key generation it seems.

See attached image.

[image]

And here also is the tMySQLOutput settings for Primary Key:

[image]

### More Work Done:

I have changed the name of the Primary Key in the tMySQL component to match the name of the tMap output area component, i get the same compile error.
I will attach this error here:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To create dynamically MySQL tables in Talend, you can use one of the "**Action on table**" options in tMysqlOutput components (in your case, "Create table...").

https://help.talend.com/reader/4I8tDQGtrOPDl5MXAS3Q~w/aDNKleHXlevILu9pnbCoNg

Don't forget to define correctly PK fields for further inserts, updates, deletes...

Then, if necessary, through your favorite Database Tool (MySQL Workbench, DBeaver or other), you can retrieve the DDL (and DML) script(s).

I hope this answers to your problem/question.

Comment: Hi Mo2s, thanks for your reply. This looks great along with the reference link. I will give this a try and let you know if i can get it to work. Thanks again.

Comment: Hi Mo2s, i ran into an issue. The table of data that comes from CSV file, does not have a primary Key. So in tMap decided to create an addition column based on an expression to create a sequence of numbers, using NumericSequence built in function(not sure if i spelled the name right here). But the tMap thru a warning saying the inputs are less than the outputs. Because now the outputs have the additional column, but this should not matter though, because all the other fields are mapped and this new primary key field should do auto increment. When i run it, says that this column is unkown.

Comment: Hi Palu. Good initiative to create a incremental surrogate key. The error encountered is in the tMap component or in the tMySQLOutput component? Is it maybe just a database error as your column is not present in your MySQL database (table has been created during a previous run and now your try to insert values in a missing field). You can also manage your incremental key directly in your database by using "your_field_name INT auto_increment" field type. You can send me your Talend project by PM if necessary.

Comment: Hi, there is no table created in MySQL previously, recall i am trying to create it via Talend open studio. So Because the table was not created before hand, it is not the case of trying to do any inserts. I need create this from Talend to create the table from scratch, so I can't do auto-increment field in the database, because the Table does not exist.

Comment: Hi Palu. Can you send me a screenshot of the tMap component (with the mapping)? And also the exact log error encountered within Talend? Have you synchronize columns in the Output composent? Thanks.

Comment: Hi Mo2s, i just updated my post with a screenshot of the tMap

Comment: Hi Palu. Your error seems to be in the tMySqlOutput componant. For more information, you can also check the "Code" tab to see the compiled Java code and localize exactly where is the error/problem. Everything seems to be good in the tMap. Have you synchronize the columns in the tMySqlComponant? In the Schema Editor, all the columns have the correct name (and not empty)? One more time, you can send me your Talend project (or just the Job as a item) without the data. I could check it and give you rapidly an answer.

Comment: In addition, I can say that your field is named "primKey" in your tMap. However, the error localized in the tMySqlOuput indicates that "PK" is unknowned. Please, check that you have the correct name for your primary key field in the tMySqlOutput.

Comment: HI, the primary Key auto-generated field is defined in the tMap in the output side to MySQL component. Yes, that is the issue it tries to say that PK is unknown. But the table does not exist yet, so how can it complain about it being Unknown!

Comment: Thanks Mo2s. I will send you even the data, not a problem. But how do we do that, do we go into PM(private message) as you mentioned earlier. Let me know,

Comment: Hi Palu. Thanks for the additional information. I'm sorry but there is no possibility for private message (my bad...). Now, I see your problem: please, remove the Additional Column(s) added, in Advanced Settings (in tMySqlOutput componant). Then, in Basic Settings, synchronize the columns. Finally, in the Schema Editor, be sur that all the output columns have a name and are not empty (it is sometime the case). Let me know if it is working now.

Comment: Hi, if this additional column is removed, how does one put in an auto-increment primary key? Because in tMap, the input fields will be less than the output fields, because i want to put an Auto-Increment primary key field.

Comment: Palu, send me your Talend project (create a .ZIP archive with export function), it's will be more easy :) => m .moss .eric @ gmail .com (without the spaces). If you can, send me your Excel file too. Thanks.

Comment: Hi, just sent you some stuff. Reply back in the email so i know you got it.